# Printing output of pandas profiling object upon click of a button

Tags: python, tkinter, pandas-profiling

My question is very specific to pandas profiling package and tkinter package. I want that on click of a button, the profiling report should be displayed in the gui window. My code is:

```
import pandas_profiling

def data_profiling():
    pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(data)

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text='EDA/Data profiling', command=data_profiling).grid(row=9, column=0)
```

Upon execution the button displays nothing. Documentation of pandas_profiling does not also help.

Comment: what pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(data) return for you? Is a simple text?

Comment: Its HTML report displayed on the terminal/jupyter notebook. I can save it as an HTML file object, but not sure how to produce it on the click of the button